# how to stop user after inserting 5 rows into table while userid is same in all 5 rows in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

code:

```
<?php
        if($this->input->post('insert'))
        {
            $data = array(
                'college_name' => $college_name,
                'name' => $_POST['name'],
                'student_id' => $student_id,
                'email' => $_POST['email'],
                'mobile' => $_POST['phone'],
                'city' => $_POST['city'],
                'course' => $_POST['course'],
                'inquiry' => $_POST['inquiry'],
                'query' => $_POST['query'],
                'date' => date('Y-m-d') 
                );

            $query = $this->db->insert('college_contact',$data);
            if($query == true)
            {
                echo "<script>alert('your enquiry submitted successfully');</script>";
            }

            $this->db->select('name');
            $this->db->from('college_contact');
            $where = "student_id = '$student_id'";
            $this->db->where($where);
            $query = $this->db->get();
            $result = $query->num_rows();
            if($result > 0)
            {
                echo "you are not allow";
            }
        }
    ?>
```

I am new in codeigniter. In this code I have created form and inserting its value into the database and now I want that if a particular student inserting 5 time data into table then he would be not allowed to insert more data into database. So, How can I do this ? Please help me.

Thank You

Comment: you can change `$result > 0` to `4`

Comment: You want to limit to 5 inserts for a period of time or for lifetime?

Comment: not at all, `$result > 5` this is what I meant.

Comment: and add that portion where you are checking count of insert,  above insert code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think,

Step:1, First you selected row count in table where `userid='$userid'`, you get current student record count.Not work data inserted to the first.

Step:2, You continue work to insert record or not allow to insert record with condition liked

```
if($record > 5){
 echo "not allowed new record";
}else{
 //continue insert query work
 *$query = $this->db->insert('college_contact',$data);*
 echo "your record is inserted";
}
```

I mean not allowed for new record if current student recored is 5 times.So, I first selected his record count and continous condition.Thank.

Answer (score 0):

While student insert when you have to check in your model:
Try this way, might it helps.

```
$student_id = your student id which you get while inserting.

$query =$this->db->select('your_student_id')
                    ->from('college_contact')
                    ->where('your_student_id',$student_id)
                    ->get();

   //Now Find Number of rows
   $number_of_rows = $query->num_rows();
   if($number_of_rows < 5){
          //Put your insert query here           

   } else {
         // Redirector gives the message that you have already inserted 5    times..or whatever you want in the message.
   }
```